# Size of iframe not adjusted dynamically on embedded dashboard

Tags: html, iframe

We have a Qucksight dashboard that is being displayed within an iframe

```
<iframe src="https://ap-southeast-2.quicksight.aws.amazon.com/.../" height="3200px" overflow="auto" width="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

the iframe gets displayed correctly and also the dashboard appears. Now the dashboard itself has multiple tabs, whereas each tab contains different content with different length.

As seen above the height is set manually to a fixed 3200px which will result in lots of empty space for tabs with less content

[image]

Now I've tried to set the height to `100%` and `auto`

```
<iframe src="https://ap-southeast-2.quicksight.aws.amazon.com/.../" height="100%" overflow="auto" width="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

which both gave the following result

[image]

What do I have to do to get the dashboards showing in full height which is dynamically adjusted when switching tabs?

UPDATE

Wrapping the iframe in a

```
<div height="100%" width="100%"><iframe...></iframe></div>
```

results in the following

[image]

UPDATE 2

Adding the height in the style as follows solves the issue

```
<iframe src="..." style="height: 100vh; width: 100%; scrolling: no; frameborder: 0"></iframe>'
```

but it creates a double scroll bar (one for the actual iframe and one for the page)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use Amazon QuickSight JavaScript SDK to generate these iframes:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-quicksight-embedding-sdk

And set height parameter to AutoFit to autoscale based on actual dashboard content height.

Example:

```
height: "AutoFit",
loadingHeight: '700px',
```

Answer (score 2):

Removing overflow from the body of the page will disable scrolling. If your iframe occupies the entire screen, as it seems to be, just add "overflow: hidden;" in the body of the page.

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Check if the property is being applied, because if you use any bootstrap template it can overwrite overflow: hidden. In this case just add the "!important" in css.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping your iframe in Div and applying height and width 100% to iframe.

Comment: You simply with `<div style="width:100%; height:100%;"><iframe ...></div>`?

Comment: Yes, Try doing that

Comment: I've tried it but the dashboard doesn't display at all anymore now

Comment: Sorry I meant apply height and width to iframe and not div, Like this
`<div ><iframe width = "100%"  height = "100%" ...></div>`

Comment: Okay it's still the same result as my last screenshot up there

Answer (score 0):

Puting the `iframe` inside of a `div` with height set to 100% should work. I have tried it before.

```
<div height="100%>
<iframe>...</iframe>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I've tried that and it squeezes the entire iframe to a very small scale, see my update above

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following and it has worked!

**HTML**

```
<iframe src="..."></iframe>
```

`...` needs to be replaced with the URL

**CSS**

```
iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

In the CSS, the `height` of the `iframe` is being set to 100% of the viewport height. (A.K.A: the height of the window)

Notes:

- `vh` is the CSS unit for viewport height. (window height)
- you can add any other property onto the iframe.
- the `height` must be set in CSS, in another file or in `style` tags
- the `vh` value can be set above 100 for more space

Hopefully, this solves your problem.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks that kind of worked now; the iframe doesn't have the empty space at the bottom anymore, however, there are 2 scrollbars now even though I set `scrolling` to no...(see updated screenshot)

Comment: You are able to set the ```vh``` value above 100. Set it to something such as ```125vh``` or whatever you see fit. Let me know if this still does not work.

Comment: Well if I set the `vh` value to something above 100, then it's the same thing as setting `px`!? One of the tabs will have the empty space again while others don't or have a scrollbar depending on the length of the content

Answer (score 0):

I think it'll help you

```
<body style="margin: 0;overflow: hidden;height: 100vh;">
      <iframe src="..." style="height: 100%;width: 100%;border: 0;"></iframe>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with AWS QuickSight Embedding SDK 2.2.2.
The best solution I found is to set `resizeHeightOnSizeChangedEvent` option to `true`:

```
      height: "300px",
      resizeHeightOnSizeChangedEvent: true,
```

Unfortunately, all settings for prior versions like using `loadingHeight` or `iframeResizeOnSheetChange` etc. didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Next JS v13.4 using the Looker SDK, in 2023**

In a Next JS v13.4 project, by accident of fat fingers, the intellisense on the Looker SDK object revealed a function, not documented anywhere on the internet as far as I can tell, called `.withDynamicIFrameHeight()`.

I tried it out and it worked straight away, Looker embed height was set dynamically and no more nasty scroll bars. Iframe integration now looks seamless in the UI.

Full example of the code that creates the Looker embed below.

```js
async function embedder(
  element: HTMLDivElement,
  id: string | number,
  onConnect?: (dashboard: LookerEmbedDashboard) => void,
  onStart?: (event: DashboardEvent) => void,
  onComplete?: (event: DashboardEvent) => void,
  onSessionStatus?: (event: SessionStatus) => void,
): Promise<void> {
  const dashboard = await LookerEmbedSDK.createDashboardWithId(id)
    .withParams({
      // theme: "dev_theme", // When you want to preview a different theme, this should match with a theme in Looker > Admin > Themes
      _theme: JSON.stringify({
        show_filters_bar: false,
      }),
    })
    .appendTo(element)
    .on("dashboard:run:start", onStart || noop)
    .on("dashboard:run:complete", onComplete || noop)
    .on("session:status", onSessionStatus || noop)
    .withDynamicIFrameHeight()  // add this to remove scrollbars on Looker dashboard
    .build()
    .connect();

  onConnect?.(dashboard);
}
```